# How to persist column descriptions in BigQuery tables

Tags: google-bigquery, yaml, etl, dbt

I have created models in my **dbt(data build tool)** where I have specified column description. In my **dbt_project.yml** file as shown below

```
models:
    sakila_dbt_project:
     # Applies to all files under models/example/
     +persist_docs:
        relation: true
        columns: true
      events:
          materialized: table
          +schema: examples
```

I have added *+persist_docs* as described by dbt as the fix to make column description appear but still no description appears in bigquery table.

My `models/events/events.yml` looks like this

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: events
    description: This table contains clickstream events from the marketing website

    columns:
      - name: event_id
        description: This is a unique identifier for the event
        tests:
          - unique
          - not_null

      - name: user-id
        quote: true
        description: The user who performed the event
        tests:
          - not_null
```

What I'm I missing?

*p.s I'm using dbt version 0.21.0*

Answer (score 0):

Looks consistent with the required format as shown in [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/persist_docs):

`dbt_project.yml`

```
models:
..[<resource-path>](resource-path):
....+persist_docs:
......relation: true
......columns: true
```

`models/schema.yml`

```
version: 2

models:
..- name: dim_customers
....description: One record per customer
....columns:
......- name: customer_id
........description: Primary key
```

Maybe spacing? I converted the spaces to periods in the examples above because the number of spaces is unforgivingly specific for yml files.

I've started using the vscode yml formatter because of how often I run into spacing issues on these keys in both the `schema.yml` and the `dbt_project.yml`

Otherwise, this isn't for a `source` or `external-table` right? Those are the only two artifacts that `persist-docs` is unsupported for.

1. Sources unsupported [persist_docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/persist_docs) -> sources tab
2. External Tables unsupported (Can't find in docs again but read today in docs or github issue)
3. Also Apache Spark unsupported (irrelevant here) [Apache Spark Profile](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/warehouse-profiles/spark-profile#supported-functionality)

Also, if you're going to be working with persist_docs a lot, check out this macro example [persist_docs_op](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4226#issuecomment-971447928) that Jeremy left for a `run-operation` to update your persisted docs in case that's all you changed!